# finding upper and lower bounds of finite sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, upper-lower-bounds

Find upper and lower bound for the following finite sum

$1/(1 + 1^3)+1/(1 +2^3)+1/(1 + 3^3) + ··· + 1/(1 + n^3)$

My attempt:

$1/(1 + 1^3)+1/(1 +2^3)+1/(1 + 3^3) + ··· + 1/(1 + n^3)$ = $\sum_{i=1}^n 1/(1+i^3)$ = $\int_1^n$1/$(1+i^3)$di = $\int_1^n1/(1+x^3)$dx

But now I'm stuck. What should I do? Is m attempt correct?

Comment: compare $\frac{1}{n^3}$ to  $\frac{1}{n^3+1}$ for each n. does the series $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n^3} $ converge? Hint, use ratio test.

Comment: I put the method, with a diagram, at your earlier question. This one is quite similar, you just need more work to find this integral. Also, this one, if you want, you can use $a=1$ and $b=n$

Comment: given continuous $f(x)$ with $f > 0$ and $f' < 0,$ we get
$$ \int_a^{b+1} \; f(x) \; dx \; < \sum_{j=a}^b \; f(j) < \int_{a-1}^b \; f(x) \; dx$$

Comment: I didn't understand the method. Can you show me how?